# Preparing binary represented data for fpgrowth on Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, data-processing, market-basket-analysis

I am currently working on the Santander Product Recommendation dataset from Kaggle to make experiments on FPGrowth.

FPGrowth algorithm from pyspark (ML) requires dataframe as item sets:

```
+---+------------+
| id|       items|
+---+------------+
|  0|   [A, B, E]|
|  1|[A, B, C, E]|
|  2|      [A, B]|
+---+------------+
```

But the data I have is in this format:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| id|  A|  B|  C|  D|  E|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|  0|  1|  1|  0|  0|  1|
|  1|  1|  1|  1|  0|  1|
|  2|  1|  1|  0|  0|  0|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

I attempted to solve it by replacing 1's with the column names and creating list from them but that did not work.

Is there a way to perform this conversion by using Spark dataframe functions?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use udf:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, struct

@udf("array<string>")
def as_basket(row):
    return [k for k, v in row.asDict().items() if v]

df.withColumn("basket", as_basket(struct(*df.columns[1:]))).show()
```

Comment: Thank you very much! By the way, is there a way to perform this by using dataframe functions of Spark?